# MissingMethodException When I Deploy MVC4 Application using TFS build

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, nuget-package

I have MVC4 application which is working perfectly when i published this manually by copying all files from local to server. I have created TFS build definition to automate the build process for this application. TFS build is coping all files correctly but when i am running application i am getting below exception.

> Method not found: 'Void
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.set_IgnoreSerializableAttribute(Boolean)'.

I checked Newtonsoft.Json.dll presence. It's available in the bin folder. This dll is comes with Nuget package. I am not getting exact problem. Please help to resolve this issue. 
Is there anything i need to do in build definitions for explicit packages? 
Why IIS is not finding method even the dll is available in bin folder?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you check local dll version as well as deployed dll version. may be both are difference. It can also create error

Comment: I checked this also. Both dll versions are same. Anything else need to look at?

Comment: It's also possible that on production machine JSON.NET is taken from GAC, can you check that option?